# как в (одном классе) перегрузке оператора+= использовать переменные (приват) с другого класса?

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, перегрузка-операторов, дружественная-функция

Возможно как то через *this но я не сильно понимаю как, и не знаю куда его втулить

```
friend day operator+=(day& dy, product& prod)
{
    dy.ygl+= prod.Yglevod;
    dy.bel+= prod.Belok;
    dy.gur+= prod.Gur;
    dy.kkal+= prod.Kkal;
    return dy;
}
```

это действие в классе `day`

`product` - это другой класс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас оператор описан как свободная функция; по-моему, вы хотели не этого. Как я понимаю, это оператор для `day` - тогда он должен быть в классе `day` и иметь вид примерно такой -

```
day& operator+=(const product& prod)
{
    ygl+= prod.Yglevod;
    bel+= prod.Belok;
    gur+= prod.Gur;
    kkal+= prod.Kkal;
    return *this;
}
```

Для такого обращения к закрытым членам `product` ваш класс `day` должен быть объявлен его другом; ну, или другом можно объявить только оператор `+=` из класса `day`.

P.S. Оператор может быть объявлен и как свободная функция, но, по-моему, для оператора `+=` логичнее быть объявленным в пределах класса, как функция-член.

P.P.S. Вот простенький пример, где операторы объявлены и в классе, и вне.

```
class A;

class B
{
public:
    B& operator +=(const A& a);
    int y;
};

class A
{
private:
    int x;

    friend B& B::operator +=(const A& a);
    friend B& operator -=(B& b, A& a);
};

B& B::operator +=(const A& a)
{
    y += a.x;
    return *this;
}

B& operator -=(B& b, A& a)
{
    b.y -= a.x;
    return b;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    B b;
    A a;
    b += a;
    B c = b -= a;
}
```

Comment: понял, недавно изучаю ооп, первый раз столкнулся с таким. сейчас пойду смотреть про дружественные классы. спасибо большое!!

Comment: Я там вам в помощь небольшой исходник в ответ дописал, смотрите.

Comment: увидел. Очень помог, спасибо!

Comment: Ну, если ответ устраивает, помечайте как принятый :)

Comment: все равно не получается.
мне нужно в классе дей создать этот метод: 
`day& operator+=(const product& prod)

    {
    ygl+= prod.Yglevod;
    bel+= prod.Belok;
    gur+= prod.Gur;
    kkal+= prod.Kkal;
    return *this;
    }`
а в классе продукт сделать этот метод дружеским. типа 
`friend day& day::operator+=(const product& prod);`
так?

Comment: Да, вы должны объявить его как дружественный в классе `product`, или, чтоб не мелочиться :) - дружественным весь класс `day`, тогда **все** его методы будут иметь доступ к закрытым членам `product`.

Comment: чтоб сделать класс дружеским нужно прописать
friend class ...
правильно?

Comment: все, сделал, работает!

Answer (score 0):

Объявите оператор дружественной функцией для обоих классов. Ниже показано, как это можно сделать

```
#include <iostream>

class B;

class A
{
public:
    friend A & operator +=(A &a, const B &b);

    explicit A(int x = 0) : x(x) {}

    std::ostream & out(std::ostream &os = std::cout) const
    {
        return os << x;
    }

private:
    int x;
};

class B
{
public:
    friend A & operator +=(A &a, const B &b);

    explicit B(int y = 0) : y(y) {}

    std::ostream & out(std::ostream &os = std::cout) const
    {
        return os << y;
    }

private:
    int y;
};

A & operator +=(A &a, const B &b)
{
    a.x += b.y;

    return a;
}

int main()
{
    A a(10);


    (a += B(20)).out() << std::endl;
}
```

Можете также включить оператор для `rvalue` правого операнда

```
friend A & operator +=(A &a, B &&b);
```

Альтернативный подход - это объявить этот оператор в одном классе членом класса, а в другом классе дружественной функцией.